# Unique index column order - is it important?

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing, unique-index

There are a lot of articles about index column order, and I got the idea. However, I found none about unique index.

Simple example: `Product` and `Category` tables having n-n relationship using `ProductCategoryMapping` table with 3 columns: identity `Id`, `ProductId` and `CategoryId`.

If I create a unique index `UN_ProductCategoryMapping_Product` with 2 columns: `ProductId` and `CategoryId`, should I also create another unique index in  opposite order, assume I sometimes want to "list all products of a category", and sometimes "list all categories a product belongs to"?

Is SQL Server smart enough to optimize in this case?

Comment: If you have a telephone directory that lists everyone in `surname, firstname` order, how useful do you think that would be if you want to know how common each first name is?

Comment: a unique index on each of those column orders would be helpful to support each of those search cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Uniqueness* doesn't depend on column order. If you state that the combination of columns 1, 2 and 3 are unique, and someone else states that the combination of columns 2, 1 and 3 are unique, you're stating the same facts.

But that's not to say that all indexes are equal, or equally useful. Indexes are only (potentially) useful if you can use all of their left-most columns. If you have a query that doesn't use the left-most column of any index, the only way to satisfy the query is to scan the whole table.

Comment: SQL Server can decide to scan the index instead of the table, so the index -can- be used even for querying for the second index column. This happends often when the index is small compared to the table(or clustered index) and the amount of lookups needed are few or none.